# Using Cookies and LocalStorage to minimize CSRF/XSS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt, local-storage

I'm currently working on securing a React application. If I use `LocalStorage` to store a JWT I'll be susceptible to XSS attack, if I use `cookies` I'm now dealing with CSRF... While I could store JWT in memory and pass it along with every request that won't allow me to persist user's session.

Here's my alternative idea:
When user signs in I send him a JWT that'll get stored in `LocalStorage` AND along with that an `httpOnly` `cookie` containing a CSRF token.

The idea is that in case of a CSRF attack the *bad guy* won't pass along the JWT, and in an XSS attack he won't be able to access the `cookie` so in either case he'd only send one out of two required items.

Any thoughts on where this implementation could potentially break?

I'm planning on experimenting with this approach tomorrow, but I've done some research and while cookies seems like a way to go I can't figure out the user persistence without jeopardizing security